# Facebook publish - what is ogurl?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use the sample php code to publish content on my facebook app's wall.
I took the php sample code form here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

I changed the APP_ID and the SECRET but I have no Idea what I need to put in the `$ogurl` variable and I couldnt find somethign that say what it is..

I assume this is shorten for "Open Graph URL" but still I dont know what it is or where I can find it.

Comment: I'm new to facebook apps so it's just a guess: maybe it's the url of the application (not the url from facebook but the real url)

Comment: @Ciprian Mocanu, I tried to put there my real web url and random urls but nothing worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to the [open graph protocol page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/),

```
og:url
   The canonical URL of your object that will be used as its permanent ID
   in the graph
```

so you have to define whatever URL you want to "define" your object. This url will become the permanent ID of this object in the graph.

Be aware that this url should be "canonical" in the sense that it is what you consider to be the "official and definitive" URL for your content / object.

you can see on the example on the facebook doc that they do :

```
curl -F 'access_token=...' \
 -F 'message=Hello Likers' \
 -F 'id=http://www.myopengraphpage.com/page1.html' \
 https://graph.facebook.com/feed
```

where id corresponds to $ogurl in the PHP code. so $ogurl must be the url of your content in the form :
    $ogurl = "http://www.myopengraphpage.com/page1.html";

Comment: now I tried to use this url > ...myweb.com/tst.html (ofcoruse this page exist, and I also added the `<meta property`.... line from the previous comment (replaced the content wiht the new url). still It doesnt work.

Comment: maybe the problem is elsewhere. can you post the php code that you have now ?

Comment: exactly the same like I gave in my post but replced the app id, secret and ogurl.. I cannot post them for security reasons. I belive you understand.

Comment: yep i understand for the secret ;-) but i do not see any code in the post, just sentences. do you mean you use exactly the PHP sample code in the "Publishing" section of facebook doc ? 1/ Do you get something in $access_token ? you can try replacing $parameters = "?" . $access_token ... by $parameters = "?access_token=" . $access_token .

Comment: Yes. I mean the PHP sample code in the "Publishing" section. I replaced what u said and rerun the php code, still nothing in the facebook.. BTW, I dont need to replace it because the variable `$access_token` holds this string at the end > access_token=blablabla...